# What is the purpose of 焉 in 「不近人情焉」?

Tags: classical-chinese

The full sentence is: 「肩吾问於连叔曰：“吾闻言於接舆，大而无当，往而不返，吾惊怖其言，犹河汉而无极也！大有迳庭，不近人情焉。”」

焉 means "where" or "at" (correct me if I'm wrong), so what does 焉 serve here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several Classical Chinese particles are of onomatopoetic origin, and have neither a fixed translation nor a fixed character representation.「焉」**sometimes** means *where* or *at*, but you'll have to rely on context to figure when this meaning applies.

Those meanings do not apply here.「焉」, in this context, is an end-of-phrase [modal particle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_particle) (句末語气詞).

> 吾聞言於**接輿**，大而無當，往而不反。吾驚怖其言，猶河漢而無極也，大有逕庭，不近人情「焉」。
>
> *I heard words from* **接輿** *which were extravagant but hollow, and irretrievable once uttered. His words frightened me;*  **(1)** *they were vast and boundless like the galaxy, polar opposite to reality, and worlds apart from the experiences of man* (2)

Two options for translating「焉」in this passage. Place one of these in their respective numbered positions:

1. *surely,*
2. !

> For reference, a passage where *where* or *at* applies as a translation to「焉」:
>
> > 《左傳・隱公元年》：＂**制**，巖邑也，虢叔死「焉」。＂
> >
> > *[Commentary of Zuo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zuo_zhuan), first ruling year of [Duke Yin of Lu](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%B2%81%E9%9A%90%E5%85%AC): "* **制** *, (name of a) strategically important city.* [虢叔](https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-hk/%E8%99%A2%E5%8F%94) *passed away*「*here*」*."*

---

**Reference:**

- 《王力古漢語字典》

Answer (score 0):

"焉" is a particle (語氣詞) in the sample sentence.

indicating 肯定, 疑問 or 感嘆:

http://dict.revised.moe.edu.tw/cgi-bin/cbdic/gsweb.cgi?o=dcbdic&searchid=W00000010967